# querySelector not working in mount() with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jquery-selectors

I am using `markdown-it-vue` to render Markdown into HTML on the fly :

```
<template>
  <div ref="content">
    <markdown-it-vue :content="content" />
    <code>foobar</code>
  </div>
</template>
```

When the props `content` is modified, the HTML content is injected at the `<markdown-it-vue>` component.

This HTML content contain some `<code>` tags and I want to replace them with something else. Unfortunately, I cannot select them with the following:

```
 mounted() {
   this.$refs.content.querySelectorAll('code').forEach(code => {
    console.log(code)
  })
},
```

Only the `<code>foobar</code>` is found, the ones in the `<markdown-it-vue>` are not found. However, they are in the DOM because if I do `console.log(this.$refs.content)` and I run `querySelectorAll('code')` on this variable from the Debug Console I get all my elements.

How can I access/replace the generated content from a sub-component?

I have tried to do it differently but with the same issues:

```
<template>
  <div ref="content">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import MarkdownItVue from 'markdown-it-vue'

let MyMarkdownItVue = Vue.extend(MarkdownItVue)

export default {
  props: {
    content: String,
  },
  mounted() {
    let md = new MyMarkdownItVue({propsData: {content: this.content}});
    md.$mount();
    // Displays the full output with all my `<code>` tags
    console.log(md.$el); 

    // But nothing is found there. I get an empty NodeList []
    console.log(md.$el.querySelectorAll('code'))
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: `markdown-it-vue` has [a watcher](https://github.com/ravenq/markdown-it-vue/blob/master/src/markdown-it-vue.vue#L73) on `content` and it reacts to it on `$nextTick`. My wild guess is you're querying before it finished rendering its contents. The first thing you should try is place your logic inside a `this.$nextTick().then(() => { /*code here */})` but I'm not guaranteeing it will work, since I'm not familiar with what the plugin does (behind the scenes). I'm expecting charts and heavier DOM not to be ready on next tick as, in turn, they might perform DOM manipulations.

Comment: @tao Wooh it just works!